# How to register decorators with Autofac when using RegisterAssemblyTypes?

Tags: c#, decorator, autofac

This is my code

```
public interface ICommandHandler<T>
{
    void Handle(T command);
}

public class CreateUserCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateUserCommand>
{
    public void Handle(CreateUserCommand command)
    {
        // do something with the command
    }
}

public class LoggingCommandDecorator<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> _commandHandler;

    public LoggingCommandDecorator(ICommandHandler<TCommand> commandHandler)
    {
        _commandHandler = commandHandler;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Logging...");

        _commandHandler.Handle(command);
    }
}
```

And here is my registration:

```
private void SetupAutofac()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // Register your MVC controllers.
    builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(WebApiApplication).Assembly);

    // OPTIONAL: Register model binders that require DI.
    builder.RegisterModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();

    var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
            .As(o => o.GetInterfaces()
            .Where(i => i.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>)))
            .Select(i => new KeyedService("Handler", i)));

    builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof(LoggingCommandDecorator<>),
                            typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
                            "Handler", "DecoratedHandler");


    var container = builder.Build();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

When I run this code I get the following exception:

> None of the constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'AspectDemo.Controllers.HomeController' can be invoked with the
>   available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'AspectDemo.Business.ICommandHandler`1[AspectDemo.Business.Users.CreateUserCommand]
>   createUserHandler' of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(AspectDemo.Business.ICommandHandler`1[AspectDemo.Business.Users.CreateUserCommand])'.

When I use the following as my registration, I don't get the exception, but I also don't have any decorators.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

What do I need to do so I can use decorators?

Note: Now I am just using one decorator, but in the end I think I have about 4-5 decorators.

Comment: Removing all your MVC logic, using your exact syntax, I can get the decorator to work as expected.  Pointing to the fact that your issue might be somewhere else?! Can you see if you can strip all the MVC logic and post code in which you still can't get the decorator to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `toKey` parameter of the `RegisterGenericDecorator` method, it result in a named registration, so you have to resolved a named `ICommandHandler`

```
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
    typeof(LoggingCommandDecorator<>), 
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
    fromKey : "Handler",
    toKey : "DecoratedHandler");
```

Then you can resolve it like this :

```
container.ResolveKeyed<ICommandHandler<CreateUserCommand>>("DecoratedHandler");
```

The `toKey` parameter is optional :

```
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
    typeof(LoggingCommandDecorator<>), 
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
    fromKey : "Handler");
```

Then you can resolve it like this :

```
container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<CreateUserCommand>>();
```

The `toKey` is usefull when you have intermediate decorator :

```
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
    typeof(LoggingCommandDecorator<>), 
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
    fromKey : "Original", 
    toKey : "Logging");

builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
    typeof(AuthorizationCommandDecorator<>), 
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
    fromKey : "Logging");
```

In this case, `ICommandHandler<CreateUserCommand>` will be decorated by `LoggingCommandDecorator<>` and `AuthorizationCommandDecorator<>`

Comment: I had provided the `toKey` parameter with "DecoratedHandler". When I leave this, everyhting works. Thanks.